# Use latex in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I tried to use latex format in matplot lib but it is not giving me space in a line. Here is my code

```
plt.figure(103)
plt.title('$V_x mean and fitting$')
plt.plot(vx_mean_fit[sig_fit],Sig[sig_fit],label='$Vx mean fit$')
plt.xlabel('$V_x$')
plt.ylabel('$z/d$')
plt.legend()
```

And here is my picture. Any idea why there is no space in title?
[image: Matplotlib plot]

Comment: Try using raw string for your text, like `r'$V_x mean and fitting$'`.

Comment: this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a raw string:

```
r'$V_x mean and fitting$'
```

Or you can explicitly escape the spaces:

```
'$V_x\ mean\ and\ fitting$'
```

Comment: Using raw strings has not effect on spaces. Also, you cannot "escape" spaces; instead, the backslash (`\`) **is** a space in latex math mode. In order to use backslashes you need to use a raw string.

Answer (score 1):

By putting the complete text in between dollar signs you ask for it to render in math mode. This is usually undesired. What you really want is probably to only render the formulae in mathmode and not the rest of the text.

```
plt.title('$V_x$ mean and fitting')
```

[image]

Note that if your formula contains backslashes (`\`) you would want to use raw strings like

```
plt.title(r'$V_x\cdot\frac{1}{2}$ mean and fitting')
```

[image]